# Use of "with" in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

Today, I came across a sentence

> He provides all students with a new badge and belt

When I read about it, I found that "with" can also be used to describe when someone receives something

In this sentence, all students receive a new badge and belt.Therefore
"with" has been used.

My question is:

If I change a sentence "He gives us salary" to "He gives us with salary". Will it be a mistake?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. *Give* does not behave the same way as *provide*. *Provide* needs *with* in the sentence you have; *give* does not.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I'd say that *provide* **permits** *with* -- "He provides all students a new badge and belt" is equally correct.

Comment: @StoneyB I'd say that it's far less idiomatic to unacceptable. [See these](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=provided+us+a%2Cprovided+us+with+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprovided%20us%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprovided%20us%20with%20a%3B%2Cc0) Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=provides+all+students+a%2Cprovides+all+students+with+a%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprovides%20all%20students%20with%20a%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be a mistake.

As cited in https://english.stackexchange.com/a/137703/218449, the sense

> The verb provide has two different subcategorisation frames:
>
> 1. provide *something* [ **to** *somebody*]
> 2. provide *somebody* **with** *something*
>
> In the first, the material provided is the object, in the second the
>   recipient is the object.

With the verb to give, the second option is not available because you can only give somebody something. The "to" is locked into the defintion (as seen on Google Dictionary below).

> freely transfer the possession of (something) **to** (someone); hand over
>   to.

The only way it would make sense would be if the with expressed a condition, like the following.

> He gives **us** *a salary* **with** *the stipulation that we show up on time.*